# Should you refrain from answering if you can't format an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, formatting

I read a comment on an answer that said this:

> If you are using a device that doesn't allow you to format answers, you shouldn't be posting answers!

The answer was correct and useful. Also, at the time of posting, it was indeed the only answer and…not formatted.

The answerer was requested to format the answer, replied by saying he or she wasn't able to do so on mobile, and then asked that someone else do it.

Then came the comment quoted above.

This meta question is not to blame anyone (that's the reason I don't link to the answer itself), but to ask the question: should anyone refrain from answering if they can't format an answer, no matter the reason?

Comment: I can format posts on mobile just fine. Just because there's no *editor support* to insert Markdown markup doesn't mean you can't do it manually. That said, that's not a reason to tell someone not to post.

Comment: The beauty of Markdown is that it's *just plain text* which can be written and formatted anywhere.

Comment: @deceze That is... if you know it ;)

Comment: Yes; if anything this is a matter of education, not of technical limitations.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire it's not a big deal to learn just a few basic rules. Sometimes I answer from a phone and it's indeed pain, but there is no problem to format a code with four spaces and make your post otherwise distinct.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Learning it is not the same as being "required" for once to answer from mobile and be clueless about it. You can learn it, but to answer a question, you not always know it before or are in the process of learning it. I don't know why the user couldn't format: he/she only said he/she was on mobile. What I mean is that we shouldn't say "he should learn it" when we don't know everything behind it. Me, the first. (and I'm not saying you said that ;) )

Answer (score 43):

If the answer is correct and useful (and not a duplicate), I'd rather see it posted than not. The odds of someone coming back later to post are probably not good. That's also why anyone in good standing can edit posts.

Comment: While I sympathise to an extent, it is worth noting that this is only a reasonable stance if people posting answers from mobile and not bothering to format them is a rare enough ocurrence.

Answer (score 24):

It depends on how important formatting would be.  If the lack of formatting makes the answer appear incorrect, incomplete, or misleading then that answer should not be posted.

On the other hand, if formatting just makes the answer better then the answer can be posted.  Keep in mind that voters can downvote such an answer if they find the formatting very poor or confusing.

In the specific situation you note

> The answer was correct and useful.

Therefore, I think the answer (even poorly formatted) should be posted.  It's generally easier to fix formatting than it is to find the correct answer.

Comment: "It's generally easier to fix formatting than it is to find the correct answer" is a beautiful summary. If I asked a question and somebody posted an answer that helped me but wasn't formatted, I'd format it myself, and then upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 11):

If the information content is good, it should be posted—regardless of whether the answerer knows how to format it or not.  The wiki-collaboration design of SE forums allow anyone with *some* editing experience to easily fix the formatting.

I frequently edit answers, particularly those with merit.  Apparently, there are very few active editors with a full command of English grammar, spelling, punctuation, etc.  So virtually all answers have room for improvement.

If answers were discouraged because someone mixes up *better then* with *better than* or *could of* with *could have*, we wouldn't have much of a website at all.

Answer (score 4):

IMO the only thing wrong here is the content of that comment, it should have referred to the formatting of the answer and not about dictating who can and cannot answer. Answering is a freedom you have, unless you're banned of course.

Answering while cutting corners, regardless of the reason you do that and the device you do that on, is a risk you are free to take. I say risk in the lightest sense of the word, its not like you're going to get hurt. Getting comments (including not constructive ones like the trigger for this question) or even a downvote or two as a result of it is part of that risk.

So should you use a phone and feel free to take less time to format your answers? Sure, go ahead. As long as you realise what you're doing and the potential response you might get to it in this quality-driven site.

Answer (score 3):

I have an different theory than the one stated in the currently most highly upvoted answer:

*"The odds of someone coming back later to post are probably not good."*

If someone's desire to answer a question is so strong that they don't mind adding a poorly (if at all) formatted answer, then I think they *do* care enough to come back to it later when they get back to a device with which they're more comfortable writing markdown.

I suppose my position is basically the same as Cody's, and I really don't understand why his wasn't better received. He's not saying that you shouldn't answer it, just that you shouldn't answer it until you're going to do it right.

There's no need to be impatient. The goal is to provide a high quality answer that will hopefully be a useful resource for many people for years to come, *not* to solve one person's problem as quickly as possible.

Comment: What if you can't get to a computer for a couple days but you can give the OP an answer that might need a little sprucing up?

Comment: It think the answer to that is somewhat subjective, and depends on how much sprucing up is needed. But a couple _days_ without a computer?! I hope nothing that awful ever happens to me. ;)

Comment: But regardless, I still believe the answer is not just for the OP, and that it's more important to answer it well (including formatting) than it is to answer it quickly.

Comment: @NathanOliver That is an edge case. It might make sense under some specific set of circumstances, but it isn't something we want to encourage.

Comment: @duplode I agree we really don't want people doing this.  I'm just checking on do we allow edge cases.

Comment: The whole point of "edge cases" is that they break the rules. This question, like all Meta questions, is seeking to establish consensus on "best practices". Posting shoddily-formatted answers is *not* a good practice. That doesn't mean it's never permissible, it just means you shouldn't do it. The answer to "should you refrain…?" is "yes". I don't know why my answer wasn't better received, either. :-) (Interestingly, it was very well received when it was first posted, and then [less so](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/342491/timeline) over the next couple of days. Meta regulars, I guess.)

Comment: If we're getting into speculation on the psychology of people interacting with the site, I'll share an anecdote: I sometimes browse SO on my phone when killing time. If I find a question I can answer, I might try to answer it there and then, and will struggle with formatting on the tiny keyboard and screen. If I give up, I probably won't ever see that question again, because next time I log on from a PC, there'll be a whole new set of questions for me to look at. I'm not going to e-mail myself notes to write the answer later; but I might click through to an answer from my profile and tidy it.

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

This isn't a special case. If you can post an answer that is *useful* and addresses the question and isn't just covering ground covered by other answers (on that question or another one), you should post it. Making a Stack Overflow answer *useful* usually (though not always) requires code, and code must be marked up properly. If you "can't" do that, don't post an answer. But you *can* do that.

## Details

> should anyone refrain from answering if they can't format an answer, no matter the reason?

The only way a person *can't* format an answer is if the device they're using is missing a way to enter the necessary markdown formatting characters. I know of no such devices. (The only character I can think of that *might* be hard to find on a device is the backtick, which is only needed for inline code markup. Even on my ancient Samsung Galaxy [I dug it up], the backtick is readily accessible: I hit the button for symbols, and then the button for the second page of symbols, and there it is. But that's only needed for inline code; code blocks require nothing but spaces.)

So really, the question contains a logical fallacy. :-) It's asking what someone should do if they can't do X, when they *can* do X.

So, two answers:

- No, don't post an answer if you **cannot** format the answer sufficiently. Perhaps post a comment suggesting what the answer might be.
  But:
- Yes, you should post an answer (subject to the usual rules of usefulness) — because you ***can*** format it sufficiently.

Note that "sufficiently" needn't be all-singing, all-dancing. It may not be as thoroughly-formatted as you'd've done if you'd been sitting at a computer. But at a minimum, code must be marked up to be clear (four spaces per line, not challenging), and in general if clarity suffers for lack of formatting, that means said formatting is necessary.

Comment: I would agree with this answer if the distinction between fully formatted and minimally formatted was more emphatic, up front and in the tl;dr. Yes, you *can* find two different kinds of brackets, backticks, etc, etc, on your phone's keyboard, but as well as entering the text, you've got to verify it, with limited preview and editing facilities. I think rather than "a logical fallacy", "can't" should be understood as "I don't have the time / patience to get this right, but want to contribute". Saying "no, don't do that" sets the bar to contribute unnecessarily high.

Comment: You don't take into account the case where the answerer is on mobile (without formatting helper) and doesn't know Markdown. If you want to play on words, everyone can program because everyone can press keys on a keyboard. I guess your logical fallacy is no better than the one you think I committed. No offense intended.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire: False equivalence. Knowing a couple of simple markdown rules (and I mean *couple*, like two) is not the same as knowing how to program. You make it seem like it's complicated. It isn't. Separately: If the help isn't available on the mobile app, it's certainly available via the mobile *browser* (I checked).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I know, that was an hyperbole.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Again, your comment focuses on *minimal* formatting, where your answer mostly talks about *proper* formatting, except for a note at the end. Knowing how to properly format all the links, bullets, inline code, etc, *does* require more than knowing two simple rules. I think all the discussions on this page are because people are making different assumptions about this distinction, and only ryanyuyu's answer makes clear that *the distinction is itself the answer*.

Answer (score -16):

Yes, if you are unable to format your posts to ensure that they are readable, either because of unwillingness, incompetence, or technical limitations, then you should refrain from answering the question until you can address that problem.

By posting incorrectly-formatted, unreadable garbage, you are making the site worse for everyone. When new users do this with their questions, we chastise them and place their questions "on hold" until they have figured out how to format them so that they are readable. The same logic should be applied to users posting answers—if they are not correctly formatted, they are subject to being downvoted and even potentially removed.

While it is true that other people can edit such answers to fix the formatting, you should not post questions *or* answers expecting other people to do your work for you. Beyond laziness, that simply doesn't scale well. Either figure out how to format posts from the device you're currently using (it really isn't that difficult to learn Markdown, which is plain-text and can be composed on any device), or wait until you are at a computer and can do it correctly.

Comment: See also [this deleted question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281704/what-do-you-do-about-incomplete-questions), in which the poster was trying to justify their incomplete question by saying they couldn't put together a complete question due to being on mobile.

Comment: IMO this totally misses the main point from the OP "The answer was correct and useful." i.e. NOT garbage at all, simply somewhat harder to read. Additionally, what's the harm of asking another person to format the answer if the technical information has been provided (usually 90%+ of the work).

Comment: If the answer contains code blocks that are not correctly formatted as code, then it becomes completely unreadable, and thus garbage. It isn't that hard to format it yourself. If you are living in some hypothetical universe where formatting it is not possible, then you really shouldn't be posting from that universe. I'm surprised this is so controversial.

Comment: If I have the choice of spending 5 minutes re-formatting an answer to make it readable and then finding it is exactly what I need, or spending 5 hours of further research to discover the same answer myself, I would rather the answer be there for me to re-format. Thus, it is not "garbage", but a useful contribution.

Comment: I think there's a big difference between "unformatted" and "unreadable garbage". So I agree (mostly) with this answer only if the post is total nonsense. However, many (perhaps most) posts can still be understood without formatting and are still useful.

Comment: I don't think there's much of a difference. Code that is dumped into an answer *without* code formatting is definitely unreadable. Special characters are often swallowed without a trace, line breaks aren't preserved, everything gets all jumbled up. Sure, bold, italics, bulleted lists, and whatever are not important. We're talking about *basic formatting* here to ensure that the answer is *minimally readable*. I guess I just don't see answers as such scarce resources that we should accept them in any form they are being offered in. This site has standards, and those standards should apply here.

Comment: @CodyGray So in summary: garbage comments are garbage, and basic formatting can be important for a question to be readable. That's fine. But it doesn't mean every question with no formatting is garbage; nor that every question where someone apologises for not formatting it fully is not readable. You expressed surprise at this being controversial, but I think it's just a miscommunication: you're taking "unformatted" as a synonym for "garbage", others are taking it as meaning "a bit awkwardly laid out".